# Letters appearing scrambled

Tags: 14.04

Every once in a while (every couple of weeks), letters seem to get scrambled up in Ubuntu. What I mean is that some letters (sometimes more, sometimes less) get replaced by weird symbols. For example now it is the letter x that got replaced by a weird h-like symbol everywhere in Ubuntu that uses this default font, for example in GIMP:

[image: letter x replaced]

What could be causing this? Sometimes a lot more letters get messed up. If I log out and log back in it's good again. I have no idea where to start solving this.

Edit: if I highlight (select) the text (for example in a search box) then the correct letter appears, although only if the number of selected characters is small. But when I unselect it again, it's bad again.

Edit2: Now another example came up:

[image]

This time it's only in LibreOffice Calc. Very strange.

Comment: I get a similar issue on my laptop after high memory usage. Does this happen to you randomly or after high memory usage like mine?

Comment: I haven't noticed such a connection. I do get some rare (one fraction of a second about once a week) flickers of a few blackish lines on screen sometimes, which may indicate video card problems. Are the fonts maybe stored in video memory and it gets corrupted?

Comment: Also, your text is a somewhat distorted, blurry version of the original, while my characters get replaced by totally unrelated and sharp symbols.

Comment: I don't really know about the fonts question. I know that my computer has a different problem but the error seemed kind of similar. Now that you say that it is not related with your memory usage I realize that the problems are different

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem on ubuntu 14.04. The letters would get scrambled or invisible almost everyday. In my case it was related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/xserver-xorg-video-intel/+bug/1432194). As you can see there's already a fix but not for *utopic*.
In my case I'm using ubuntu *trusty* but because of [Stack Enablement](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) my xserver drivers were the *utopic* version.

### Solution

To fix it all you have to do is remove the utopic drivers and install the trusty ones.

**First remove**: `sudo apt-get purge linux-generic-lts-utopic xserver-xorg-lts-utopic linux-headers-generic-lts-utopic linux-image-generic-lts-utopic libgl1-mesa-glx-lts-utopic libegl1-mesa-drivers-lts-utopic`

**Then reinstall:** `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-input-synaptics libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386`