# Disappear some symbols in system

Tags: 14.04

At random times, my system disappears one or more symbols in different programs. It may be a gedit, terminal, IDE, etc.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Sample of problem

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running a memtest session to check for RAM errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/615115/letters-appearing-scrambled

Comment: @Elder Geek, I don`t try it.
@Dario Salvati, maybe it is my case. I try it.

Comment: Bad news guys, but problem not disapear. 
This problem not occur only in browser.